# How to track values provided from different configuration sources in ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

I have a ASP.NET Core application with multiple configuration sources(YAML, JSON, CustomConfigurationProvider). Is is possible to figure out from which source I will receive configuration values?

Comment: Always the last registered one which contains the key ^^

Comment: i.e. if you have the key "mykey" defined in yaml and json and have them registered as `.AddYamlFile(...).AddJsonFile(...)` then json overrides the value in yaml. If its `.AddJsonFile(...).AddYamlFile(...)`, then yaml overrides the json value

Comment: Can you tell Yaml or Json file will provide values for you? For example some values can exists in Yaml file and another one in Json.

Comment: See my first comment. The value provided by the **LAST registered** configuration provider which contains the given key will be used. In above example `.AddJsonFile(...).AddYamlFile(...)` if a value is not provided in yaml it will take it from json. If yaml has the key, the value from yaml will be taken. The order of the `.AddXxx()` calls matter

Comment: I need to now source of that value in runtime, is that provided from JSON or from YAML.